# How to stop output separated by blank lines with xmllint

Tags: command-line, shell-script, xml, newlines, xpath

I have the following xml generated from Gnote:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<note version="0.3" xmlns:link="http://beatniksoftware.com/tomboy/link" xmlns:size="http://beatniksoftware.com/tomboy/size" xmlns="http://beatniksoftware.com/tomboy"><title>things</title><text xml:space="preserve"><note-content version="0.1" xmlns:link="http://beatniksoftware.com/tomboy/link" xmlns:size="http://beatniksoftware.com/tomboy/size">things
<list><list-item dir="ltr">sheets
</list-item><list-item dir="ltr">test
</list-item><list-item dir="ltr">eval</list-item></list>
asd
</note-content>
</text><last-change-date>2023-02-19T12:20:06.551763Z</last-change-date><last-metadata-change-date>2023-02-19T12:20:06.553010Z</last-metadata-change-date><create-date>2023-02-19T10:40:01.309068Z</create-date><cursor-position>90</cursor-position><selection-bound-position>-1</selection-bound-position><width>649</width><height>282</height></note>
```

I want all the text content in `<note-content></note-content>` without extra newlines. This includes text content in list/list-item elements. The content requested is the following including the format:

```
things
sheets
test
eval
asd
```

After much trial and error, parsing the xml with `xmllint --xpath "//*[local-name()='note']/*[local-name()='text']/*[local-name()='note-content']/text() | //*[local-name()='note']/*[local-name()='text']/*[local-name()='note-content']/*[local-name()='list']/*[local-name()='list-item'][@dir='ltr']/text()[normalize-space()]" a.xml` (with or without `--noblanks`) yields output separated by extra newline/blank lines (there is a supposed to be a blank line after `asd` but the code block isn't showing it):

```
things

sheets

test

eval

asd
```

Removing the new lines in the xml file and using the same xmllint command outputs desired output with no extra newlines/blank lines so I don't know if this is Gnote producing something non-standard.

I tried looking at the comments and answers at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11776910/xpath-expression-to-remove-whitespace/11777638, but I've been unsuccessful. Some observations:

1. When I tried to execute (notice the `|`) `xmllint --xpath "normalize-space(//*[local-name()='note']/*[local-name()='text']/*[local-name()='note-content']/text()) | normalize-space(//*[local-name()='note']/*[local-name()='text']/*[local-name()='note-content']/*[local-name()='list']/*[local-name()='list-item'][@dir='ltr']/text())" a.xml`
   I get:

> XPath error : Invalid type
>
> XPath evaluation failure

2. Even if I reworked my script to execute multiple xmllint invocations I'm left with a single string where the newlines are removed, which is good, but which string needs to be manually set before hand. So for example here's both normalize-space and translate(normalize-space, ' ', '') variations for the note-content element path:
   `xmllint --xpath "normalize-space(//*[local-name()='note']/*[local-name()='text']/*[local-name()='note-content']/text())" a.xml xmllint --xpath "translate(normalize-space(//*[local-name()='note']/*[local-name()='text']/*[local-name()='note-content']/text()), ' ', '')" a.xml`
   Both yield one of the same two items in the note-content element without newlines ([1] is things and [2] is asd). I can choose between the two by appending [1] or [2] to text(), but this doesn't work if I have an undefined number of items. (I don't know if there is a way to just get all of the text array/items this way).
3. Some answers suggest using `[normalize-space() = 'desiredtext']`, this doesn't work if I can't expect the text in the generated xml.
4. If I just have `[normalize-space()]` after `text()`:
   `xmllint --noblanks --xpath "//*[local-name()='note']/*[local-name()='text']/*[local-name()='note-content']/text()[normalize-space()] | //*[local-name()='note']/*[local-name()='text']/*[local-name()='note-content']/*[local-name()='list']/*[local-name()='list-item'][@dir='ltr']/text()[normalize-space()]" a.xml`
   I'm left with the same output I started with.
5. I tried appending `[not(.='')]` after `text()` I get the same output.

**The question:**
I want to know if this excessive blankline behavior is caused by incorrect xmllint/xpath commands or due to the way Gnote generated the xml and the correct xmllint/xpath commands if there are any. I am not looking to use xmlstarlet because it doesn't appear to be maintained anymore. This question is not asking for a way to pipe this into a command that removes extra newlines.

Comment: I want all the text in <text></text> and not have extra \n after each. Ok, lets say sheets has an embedded new line, but why is there a newline in output after at least eval? I feel like whatever is going to get eval to not output a successive newline may also ignore the embedded new lines in the other parts of the file.

Comment: I don't think newline in xml matters for this as I'm under the impression xml does not care about standard text line feeds just tags https://sbnwiki.astro.umd.edu/wiki/Welcome_to_the_SBN_Wiki https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35504890/how-to-add-a-newline-line-break-in-an-xml-file

Comment: @roaima When I used initial xpath in question as xmlstarlet sel -t -v "//*[local-name()='note']/*[local-name()='text']/*[local-name()='note-content']/text() | //*[local-name()='note']/*[local-name()='text']/*[local-name()='note-content']/*[local-name()='list']/*[local-name()='list-item'][@dir='ltr']/text()[normalize-space()]" -n a.xml I got the same output with the extra newlines so it seems xpath needs to be adjusted.

Comment: I meant to say <note-content></note-content>, but I updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you have expressed a preference to avoid `xmlstarlet`, it will do exactly what you want:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//_:note-content' -n xmlfile
```

Output

```
things
sheets
test
eval
asd
```

Using `xmllint` I cannot avoid the blank lines that are part of the element value text:

```
xmllint --xpath '//*[local-name()="note-content"]//text()' xmlfile
```

Output

```
things

sheets

test

eval

asd
```

After having spent some time with `xmllint` I would suggest that you simply remove the blank lines. (Not ideal, but certainly effective.)

```
xmllint … | grep .
```

Output

```
things
sheets
test
eval
asd
```

Comment: Would upvote if I had enough reputation because of improved command. It's funny, when I was doing trial and error I did that but with double quotes so I got XPath set is empty and was none the wiser.

Comment: @Yetoo if it solves your problem you can definitely accept it ✔ as your chosen answer